# File uploads empty string

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Uploading an image into a directory, it seems to always try upload "" which is nothing. Rather then an actual image. What am I doing below. I know the value is "" because of what it inserts into the database.

```
<li class="formProductImage">
<span>Image:</span>
<input type="file" name="productImage" /> 
</li>
```

and the php:

```
if ($_FILES["productImage"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["productImage"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["productImage"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["productImage"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["productImage"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["productImage"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
    $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['productImage']['name']);

      $query = "UPDATE products SET image = '$filename' WHERE name = '$name'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            // Show thank you message
            echo '<span style="color:green;">Your image was added to database correctly.</span>';

            if (file_exists("uploaded/" . $_FILES["productImage"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["productImage"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productImage"]["tmp_name"],
                "uploaded/" . $_FILES["productImage"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "uploaded/" . $_FILES["productImage"]["name"];
            }

        } else {
            echo '<font color="red">Image note inserted into database.</font>';
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    }
                    }

                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: woohoo it works you legend, such a simple thing I missed from this book I am reading lol sigh! time to go opticians i think haha.

Comment: Hehe, I did the same mistake myself once and now I always think about it when creating file uploads :)

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

to :

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['productImage']['name']);
```

Comment: good spot but this hasn't solved the issue. Doesn't solve the "" string in the db either.